# Angular2 rc routes on separate pages with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, angular

everyone. I'm a bit stumped regarding the Angular2 rc1/rc2 router. I have a setup that consists of several html pages, all of which are routed by htaccess and need to have an angular2 app run ontop of them. .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
//remove .html form the url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
//not a file or a folder? It's index.html!
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

I've defined routes like this:

```
@Routes([
    {
        path: '/*',
        component: WebWireComponent
    },
    {
        path: "/admin",
        component: LoginComponent
    }
])
```

the admin route works ok, the index route works ok, but when I go to `site.com/something`, `.htaccess`resolves it to the something.html, which is exactly the same in its contents, as index.html, in the way that it includes the angular app. However, with this setup, the angular2 app does not initialize... Static content from the rest of the something.html is displayed, but nothing else. How could I make this setup work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started to work on it's own, after

```
{
   path: '/**',
   component: WebWireComponent
},
```

as the first route.